# Split a String On A Word By Words

Tags: c++, strings

I'm working on a text based rpg game and a couple of commands make use of a target and container pattern. So I wrote this function to split the string up on a given word and put it back together. I'm not sure how efficient it will be in the real world, but I think that it can be improved.

An example of such input and output would be:

```
splitOnWord("turkey leg from table", "from") -> {"turkey leg", "table"}
```

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVector;

StringVector splitOnWord(std::string line, std::string word){
    std::stringstream sstr(line);
    StringVector tmp;
    std::string str;
    int rescnt = 0;

    sstr >> str;
    tmp.push_back(str);
    while(sstr >> str) {
        if(str == word) {
            ++rescnt;
            tmp.push_back(std::string());
        } else {
            tmp[rescnt] += ' ';
            tmp[rescnt] += str;
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not overly fond of the `tmp.push_back(std::string());`.

I'd rather some of the names were clearer and more readable--for example, I'm not entirely sure what `rescnt` is supposed to mean.

Under the circumstances, I'd tend to wonder whether we're getting enough good out of the `stringstream` to justify its existence either. They can be handy, but here we don't seem to be putting the capabilities to a whole lot of use.

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string const &in, std::string const &word) {
    std::vector<std::string> ret;

    int begin = 0;
    int end = 0;

    while (std::string::npos != (end = in.find(word, begin))) {
        ret.push_back(in.substr(begin, end-begin));
        begin = end + word.length()+1;
        while (::isspace(in[begin]))
          ++begin;
    }
    ret.push_back(in.substr(begin));
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would extend this even further to have iterator support and other `std::basic_string` instantiations. The extension might not be worth it if the project is small and unlikely to change.

```
template <typename CharT, typename CharTraits, 
          typename Allocator, typename OutputIt>
OutputIt split_on_word(const std::basic_string<CharT, CharTraits, Allocator>& in, 
                       const std::basic_string<CharT, CharTraits, Allocator>& word, 
                       OutputIt out)
{
      ...
}
```

Supporting other string types might be a good thing for internationalization. Also adding a check if the value type of iterator is the same as string type would be a good boon in debugging template issues or avoiding some bugs.

Nevertheless, the extension will require creating and resizing a vector, or using `std::back_inserter`. So it really should be weighed if the extension worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

There is an even simpler solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719538/how-to-use-stringstream-to-separate-comma-separated-strings

You can define a separator between the different words of a stream, which of course can also be any word you like